# How to make new tab on excel depending on the name, whilst adding data with queries?

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I was wondering how I would go about making a macros which reads off a list of specific URL variables and makes a data query and a new sheet for a different name.

For example in my url tab I have this:

```
        1
Daniel  Butler      2017    1
Daniel  Butler      2018    1
Jack    Riewoldt    2007    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2008    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2009    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2010    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2011    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2012    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2013    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2014    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2015    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2016    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2017    2
Jack    Riewoldt    2018    2
```

What I want is to be able to have a tab for "dan butler" and "jack riewoldt" with their stats for each year in their tab. So for example the dan butler tab would have his 2017 and 2018 stats in it. From my url tab you can see numbers 1 and 2 in the side. What I would expect is that the macro would read the column with the 1s and 2s and will only make a new tab if that number changes as it loops through.

The url I use is this The URL I have is this: http://www.fanfooty.com.au/players/year.php?firstname=Dylan&surname=Grimes&year=2018

As you can see the only variables are the first and last name and the year.

What I currently have is this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetAllUrls()
Dim wsURL As Worksheet
Set wsURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("URL") 'here we define the urls worksheet

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 14 'we assume the data is in A1 to C14 (A=name, B=surname, C=year)
    AddConnection wsURL.Cells(i, 1), wsURL.Cells(i, 2), wsURL.Cells(i, 3)
Next i
End Sub

Public Sub AddConnection(Name, Surname, Year)
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.add(After:=ActiveSheet) 'add a new sheet
ws.Name = Left(Name & " " & Surname & " " & Year, 31) 'rename sheet (sheet names must be max 31 characters)

With ws.QueryTables.add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.fanfooty.com.au/players/year.php?firstname=" & Name & "&surname=" & Surname & "&year=" & Year _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = Name & " " & Surname & " " & Year
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Name` a variable?  If so, change it's name; it's a reserved word (for example `ws.Name = Name` is going to confuse things.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this a try and see if this is what you were trying to achieve.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim destCell As Range

Public Sub GetAllUrls()
Dim wsURL As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim x, dict
Dim shName As String

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Not LCase(ws.Name) Like "url*" Then ws.Delete
Next ws
Set wsURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("URL") 'here we define the urls worksheet
x = wsURL.Range("A1:C14").Value
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1) 'we assume the data is in A1 to C14 (A=name, B=surname, C=year)
    shName = x(i, 1) & " " & x(i, 2)
    If Not dict.exists(shName) Then
        dict.Item(shName) = ""
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
        ws.Name = shName
        Set destCell = ws.Range("A1")
        destCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shName)
        Set destCell = ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2, 1)
        destCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
    AddConnection ws, x(i, 1), x(i, 2), x(i, 3)
    ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
Next i

Set dict = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub AddConnection(ByVal destSheet As Worksheet, Name, Surname, Year)

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.fanfooty.com.au/players/year.php?firstname=" & Name & "&surname=" & Surname & "&year=" & Year _
    , Destination:=destCell)
    .Name = Name & " " & Surname & " " & Year
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
destCell.CurrentRegion.Borders.Color = vbBlack
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will give it a go soon and update you , thanks you guys for the responses

Comment: Hey mate thanks for this!!!, I just tried it, it works, except it only works if i delete , "For each ws in thisworkbook.... next ws" lines, kind of odd, but it works thanks!!! why is that the case that if i delete those lines it works, i get an object error if i keep it in

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked as desired. I added those lines in order to delete existing sheets with query output. If you don't need that, just delete them. Also, please take a minute to `accept the answer` to mark your question as `Solved`. :)

Comment: No wonder haha there wasnt any existing sheets , was that just a backup incase there was more sheets created that wasnt need to? Thanks! Ive marked it as a solution , you are a pro at this !